# Ionic 5, the ion-datetime component does not select a range of dates

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 5 with `ion-datetime` component. My requirement is to pick 2 dates but for some reasons the component does not let me pick more than one date. Below is the code I have:

```html
<ion-row>
  <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-datetime presentation="date" multiple="true" preferWheel="false" [(ngModel)]="packageEstimatedDated"></ion-datetime>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproduction of the issue.  It appears to work just fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8nzwdr

Comment: What version of ionic are you using? the multiple option is in ionic 6+. please add result of `ionic info` command to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple Date Selection only works on ionic v6 or later you can check the v5 document from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/api/datetime).

To achieve that I prefer you upgrade to v6 or you can use a third-party library like `ion2-calendar` you can check this [article](https://getwillzone.blogspot.com/2018/05/ionic-3-multiple-select-date-from.html)

Answer (score 0):

The ion-datetime component does not allow to select a range of dates, although there is a [feature request](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/23572) to Ionic to add this option to the component. Currently the component only allow to select multiple days, but the user has to click every day who wants to select.

There are third party components that provide this feature like [ion2-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion2-calendar?activeTab=readme) or [Ion Range Calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlproxer/ion-range-calendar?activeTab=readme) (this for @ionic/angular >= 7). Check the component requirements before importing to the project.